# JavaScript: How to force a page reload on reset?

Tags: forms, events, google-chrome, cross-browser, reload

I have a page with some generated HTML that survives the form's `reset` button. It is a problem because that HTML is inconsistent with the values in the cached default form.

In principle I guess it could be solved easily if I could force a hard reload from the server when the user presses the `reset`. However I see that the Chrome browser does not support the onReset event (in fact it is deprecated in HTML5).

But perhaps I could work around the missing onReload event. Can I re-define what happens when the `reset` button is pressed? In my case the `apply` and `reset` buttons are located in general HTML templates which I cannot change. Can I attach a function to the button from JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the "reset" button , by a regular button.
And use the "onClick" event, to trigger a page reload.

**EDIT**

oops I missed the template part,

You can add a function to a button from Javascript.
First you need to "get" the button, with something like `document.getElementbyId('resetButton');`

If the button doesn't have a ID, you still can to retrieve it by doing [javascript dom traversal](http://oreilly.com/catalog/jscript4/chapter/ch17.html)

then you can add a function like :

```
var resetButton = document.getElementbyId('resetButton');
resetButton.onclick= reloadPage;

function reloadPage(){
   window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Yes, OK. The complication is that the 'reset' button is in a template which I cannot modify. That's why I asked if I can replace the button's behavior somehow...

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answers are really clear and helpful.